# instantiate class in python as a callable object

Tags: python, django

I found this block of code which instantiates a class with an object 
but we used it as a callable  even without defining a `__call__` method.
Here is the code of the class in Django source code on Github 
[code of the class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L8)

You can see the instantiation at the bottom of page, too
and here we used it used it by inheriting from it:

```
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
def _make_hash_vlaue(self, user, timestamp):
    return (str(user.pk)+str(timestamp)+str(user.is_active))

account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

Here is the call of the instantiated instance in the token key of the dictionary:

```
message = render_to_string('acc_activate_email.html',
                                    {'user': new_user, 
                                     'domain': current_site.domain,
                                     'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.pk),
                                     'token': account_activation_token(new_user))})
```

You can take a look at the original code here 
[original code where we used the object](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef)

Comment: This will still fail because you are only passing a `user`, not a `timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your question was made prior to the aforementioned code from the article, but the actual code now is

```
'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
```

which would be a proper call of the `make_token` method.  With the code you had pasted above, calling `account_activation_token(user)` would raise a `TypeError: 'TokenGenerator' object is not callable error.

Comment: yes, that's what happened when i am tried to make it like what he did, i thought it was because of me as there are many people commented without mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `__call__` method on the class:

```py
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def make_token(self, user, timestamp):
        return (str(user.pk)+str(timestamp)+str(user.is_active))

    def __call__(self, user, password):
        return self.make_token(user, timestamp)


t = TokenGenerator()
t(someuser, sometimestamp)
# some hash
```

However, I'm not really convinced you *need* to, as you have a class where the `make_token` method doesn't reference anything in the class at all. A function would do just as much here:

```py
generate_token(user, timestamp):
    return (str(user.pk)+str(timestamp)+str(user.is_active))

generate_token(someuser, sometimestamp)
# some hash
```

Realistically, the way they use it in the docs is by calling that instance method from the instance like:

```py
t = TokenGenerator()

t._make_hash_vlaue(someuser, sometimestamp)
```

Comment: i really appreciate that , i just wanted to know what is going on with the code as 
@mcabrams told me , thanks a lot